# SQL Query: How do i get list of address and number of orders to each address

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables

One contains a list of users addresses, the other table contains list of orders.

What I want to do is join the tables, get a distinct list of address and the number of orders to the address.

```
Table1
ID    - USERNAME    - USERADDRESS
1     - USER1       - ADRESS1
2     - USER2       - ADDRES2
3     - USER3       - ADDRES3

Table2
ID    - USERID      - ORDERDETAIL
1     - 3           - ...
2     - 2           - ...
3     - 2           - ...
4     - 1           - ...
5     - 3           - ...
6     - 2           - ...
7     - 1           - ...
8     - 3           - ...
9     - 3           - ...
10    - 3           - ...
```

And Get

```
ADDRESS1   2
ADDRESS2   3
ADDRESS3   5
```

How can i do this in one SQL statement?

Comment: If you give us table definitions, sample data and expected result, it'd be much easier to help you...

Comment: And add the tag for the DBMS you are using. Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check this query:

```
select a.address, count(o.order_num) orders from addresses a inner join orders o on a.address_id = o.address_id GROUP BY a.address
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, you should state the RDBMS and post your attempt. The general approach to joining and applying an aggregate would be such:

```
SELECT t1.USERADDRESS, 
       COUNT(t2.ID) as NumOrders -- Show each address and a count of orders
FROM Table1 t1
   INNER JOIN Table2 t2
   on t2.USERID = t1.ID -- JOIN Key
GROUP BY t1.USERADDRESS;
```